# How do I read and write an excel sheet from and to S3 using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, openpyxl

I have a excel file in S3. My aim is to read that file, process and write it back. I have been using openpyxl to achieve the read and write part of it and it works locally. However the same doesn't work when the file is located is S3.

The current architecture is as follows. A call is made to my flask app where the URL to the file in S3 is passed as a parameter. The parameter is read as follows.

```
url = request.args.get('url')
```

In case of a csv file; the following had worked

```
pandas.read_csv(url)
```

But in dealing with xlsx files, the following (with openpyxl) :

```
file = load_workbook(filename = url)
corpus = file['Sheet']
```

is giving me the following error :

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 's3.amazonaws.com/data-file/prod/projects/Methane__-oil_and_gas-_-_Sheet1.xlsx'
```

How do I resolve this and read this file from S3. Also, after I am done processing, how do I write it back to S3.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a url in `pandas.read_csv` as it automatically recognizes url's but it looks like the url doesnt have the protocol from your error.

The url should be `https://s3.amazonaws.com/data-file/prod/projects/Methane__-oil_and_gas-_-_Sheet1.xlsx`

Try appending `https://` before the url and see what happens.